# Validate all inputs are entered an total equals 100

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form with 6 input boxes. I'd like to validate that the user has filled in each input with a number and that the numbers total 100 exactly. I have a function that will validate if the numbers total more than 100, but how do I validate for under 100? Right now I get an error before all values are entered.

HTML

```
<fieldset>      
     <input  type="text" name="qty"  id="qty1" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                          
     <input  type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                           
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty3" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                         
     <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                              
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty5" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                            
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty6" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>        
</fieldset>      
<output type="text" name="total" id="total" class="hvr-pop" readonly placeholder="Must total 100"></output>
```

JavaScript

```
    function findTotal() {
        "use strict";
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var tot = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

                }
            }                       
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;   
        // check that weightage scores = 100    
        if (tot > 100 ) {   
            alert("Please make sure numbers total 100.");
                $("input").focus(function() {
                     $( this ).css( "border-color", "red" ).val("");
                });
                $('#form1').find('#total').val('');
                return false;
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing the validation `oninput` instead of using a button to trigger it? If you are checking if the total is less than 100 every time someone enters something, they're going to be getting an alert every time they enter a value.

Comment: Are you doing anything differently if it's more or less than 100?  If the result is the same no matter high or low as long as it's not equal to 100, you can just use != or !== (depending on type safety)

Comment: If the total of the 6 inputs is less than or greater than 100, an alert should be  triggered. If I use !== instead of >, an alert pops up before all inputs are entered.

Comment: Also,I can't trigger it on a button, the client is asking it be done oninput , if possible

Comment: It's going to be a terrible user experience if you do it `oninput`, the user will have to dismiss an alert window around 11 times just to finish filling out the fields. If anything, at least wait until all fields have a value before running the validation.

Comment: If the client wants it done on input, they must realize that it makes no sense to alert before all the values are initially entered. You should detect and alert only when all six fields have a value. After that, any change to the input could trigger your alert. It seems like that's what they mean about not wanting to have to push a button every time.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aaron mentioned above, you can simply change the `greater than` sign to a `does not equal` sign if you are going to treat both less than or more than 100 the same way:

```html
<fieldset>      
     <input  type="text" name="qty"  id="qty1" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                          
     <input  type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                           
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty3" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                         
     <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                              
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty5" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                            
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty6" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>        
</fieldset>      
<output type="text" name="total" id="total" class="hvr-pop" readonly placeholder="Must total 100"></output>

<script>
    function findTotal() {
        "use strict";
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var tot = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

                }
            }                       
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;   
        // check that weightage scores = 100    
        if (tot !== 100 ) {   
            alert("Please make sure numbers total 100.");
                $("input").focus(function() {
                     $( this ).css( "border-color", "red" ).val("");
                });
                $('#form1').find('#total').val('');
                return false;
            }   
    }
</script>
```

However, as I mentioned, this is a bad user experience because the validation is happening every time someone enters a value into the input, meaning they will have to dismiss multiple alert windows just to fill out all the inputs. Instead, you should validate on the click of a button, or at the very least, wait until all inputs have a value before validating.

Comment: Yes, I agree. What I want to validate is that all the inputs are entered before an alert pops up. Don't know how to do that, if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, add below if condition

```
if (tot < 100 && arr[5].value) {
    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].value = null;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>      
     <input  type="text" name="qty"  id="qty1" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                          
     <input  type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                           
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty3" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                         
     <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                              
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty5" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>                            
     <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty6" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>        
</fieldset>      
<output type="text" name="total" id="total" class="hvr-pop" readonly placeholder="Must total 100"></output>
```

JS:

```
   function findTotal() {
        "use strict";
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var tot = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

                }
            }                       
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;   
        // check that weightage scores = 100    
        if (tot > 100 ) {   
            alert("Please make sure numbers total 100.");
                $("input").focus(function() {
                     $( this ).css( "border-color", "red" ).val("");
                });
                $('#form1').find('#total').val('');
                return false;
            }   

 if (tot < 100 && arr[5].value) {
    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].value = null;
    }
  }



    }
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yJWoLA

Comment: @updated codepen which works for total less than 100.. Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks, Naga Sai A. This works great for less than 100, but now if it is exactly 100, I get an alert.

Comment: I am not getting alert ..can give sample values you entered , i tried 10,20,30,30,5,5

Comment: No, I think what I want can't done. If a user inputs a 2 digit number in the last box,an alert will pop up after the first number, so he is not able to put in the entire number. But, thanks for your help Naga Sai A